# How to classify string as 'good', 'bad', and 'mixed' based on sequences of vowels and consonants

Tags: javascript, string, loops, text-classification

I want to categorize strings into three types: good, bad, or mixed. If a string has 3 consecutive vowels or 5 consecutive consonants, or both, then it is categorized as bad. Otherwise it is categorized as good. Vowels in the English alphabet are ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] and all other letters are consonants.

The string can also contain the character `?`, which can be replaced by either a vowel or a consonant. This means that the string "?aa" can be bad if `?` is a vowel or good if it is a consonant. This kind of string is categorized as mixed.

Implement a function that takes a string `s` and returns its category: good, bad, or mixed.

Below is the current code that I have:

```js
function classifyStrings(s) {
  if (s.includes('?')) return 'mixed';

  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i].match(/[aeiou]/gi) && s[i + 1].match(/[aeiou]/gi) && s[i + 2].match(/[aeiou]/gi)) {
      return 'bad'
    } else {
      return 'good'
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to get someone to solve your exam.

Comment: As an assist, with regEx you can use a construct like this /[aeiou]{3,}/gi to determine if there is at least three vowels in a row. I would recommend [this site](https://regex101.com/) to get better acquainted with regEx and its many facets (although there are many good ones.

Comment: @rasmeister I tried your solution, but below code doesn't seem to work. Do you know why??

if(s[i].match(/[aeiou]{3}/)) return 'bad'

Comment: You don't need the loop. Just use `/[aeiou]{3,}/i` to test against the whole string, `s`.

Comment: If the input contains one bad substring, and one mixed substring, then overall is it considered bad or mixed?

Comment: How would you classify `aa?bbbb`?

Answer (score 3):

Define two regexps, one for mixed and one for bad.

The `bad` regexp simply looks for three consecutive vowels or five consecutive consonants. The `mixed` regexp looks for the same thing, but uses lookahead `(?=`) to ensure that there is a question mark somewhere within the next three or five characters.

```js
const bad = /[aeiou]{3}|[^aeiou?]{5}/;
const mixed = /(?=.{0,2}\?)[aeiou?]{3}|(?=.{0,4}\?)[^aeiou]{5}/;

function classify(s) {
  return bad.test(s) ? "bad" : mixed.test(s) ? "mixed" : "good";
}

['abcde', 'aeibbb', 'xxaa?s', 'aavwxy?aa', 'abcdfga', 'aa?bbbb'].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s, classify(s)));
```

Comment: this fails for `aa?bbbb`

Comment: It (now) returns `mixed` for `aa?bbbb`, which I think is correct, because there are no "bad" substrings, only "mixed" substrings". if you disagree, please ask the OP.

Comment: Given that possible values for "?" can be vowel or consonant. So for given input "aa?bbbb" it takes either "aaabbbb" or "aabbbbb" and both are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution in 3 steps:

1. **Identifying Bad Strings**.
   This line checks if the string s has either 3 consecutive vowels `[aeiou]{3}` or 5 consecutive consonants `[^aeiou?]{5}`. If either of these conditions is met, the string is classified as bad.
2. **Handling `'?'` in Strings.**
   In essence, this solution adopts a recursive approach. When it encounters a `?`, it explores both possibilities (vowel and consonant) by replacing the `?` and then re-evaluating the string. If both possibilities lead to the same result, that result is returned; otherwise, it returns mixed.
3. **Identifying Good Strings.**
   If neither of the above conditions is met, it means the string doesn't have 3 consecutive vowels or 5 consecutive consonants or a `?`. Therefore, it's classified as good.

```js
function classifyStrings(s) {
//1. Identifying Bad Strings:
  if(s.match(/[aeiou]{3}/) || s.match(/[^aeiou?]{5}/)) return 'bad';
  
//2. Handling '?' in Strings:        
  if(s.match(/\?/)){
    var a=classifyStrings(s.replace(/\?/, 'a'));
    var b=classifyStrings(s.replace(/\?/, 'b'));        
    if(a==b) return a
    return 'mixed'
  }
  
//3. Identifying Good Strings:
  return 'good'
}

['abcde', 'aeibbb', 'xxaa?s', 'aavwxy?aa', 'abcdfga', 'aa?bbbb'].forEach(s => console.log(s, classifyStrings(s)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres an 'almost' answer

```js
function isVowel(s){
  return s=="a" || s=="i" || s=="o"  || s=="u"  || s=="e";
}

var inputs = ["aaa","aab","aabbbbb","aa?bbbb","?aa", "bbaa?"]
//             bad   good   bad       bad      mixed  mixed   
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
  var letters = inputs[i].split("");
  var vcount = 0; ccount = 0;
  var mixed = false;
  for(var j=0;j<letters.length;j++){
    if(isVowel(letters[j])){
      ccount=0;
      vcount++;
    }else if(letters[j]=="?"){
      mixed = true;
    }else{
      vcount=0;
      ccount++;
    }
  }
  if(mixed){
    var possibilities = ["ifVowel","ifConsonant"];
    var outcome = [];
    for(var p=0; p<possibilities.length; p++){
      var tvcount = 0; tccount = 0;
      for(var l=0; l<letters.length;l++){
        if(isVowel(letters[l])){
          if(tccount!=5) tccount=0;
          tvcount++;
        }else if(letters[l]=="?"){
          if(possibilities[p]=="ifVowel"){
            if(tccount!=5) tccount=0;
            tvcount++;
          }else {
            if(tvcount!=3) tvcount=0;
            tccount++;
          }
        }else{
          if(tvcount!=3) tvcount=0;
          tccount++;
        }
      }
      if(tvcount==3 || tccount==5){
        outcome.push("bad");
      }else{
        outcome.push("good");
      }
    }
    if(outcome[0]!=outcome[1]) console.log("mixed");
    else console.log(outcome[1]);
  }else{
    if(vcount==3 || ccount==5) console.log("bad");
    else console.log("good");
  }
}
```

However, this fails if there's more than one "?". Probably could fix this with recursion, but already spend 30 mins on this one, so have to move on :(

Hope this helps

Comment: Shouldn't `aa?bbbb` be "mixed"?

Comment: @torazaburo no, because both possibilities results bad